# Get a log of kernel updates

Tags: kernel, updates, log

How do I get a timestamped list of kernel updates? I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Does `zgrep 'install linux-headers' /var/log/dpkg.log* | sort | cut -f1,2,4 -d' '` help?

Comment: One easy way to check if a kernel update is responsible is to [expose your grub menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time) and select an older kernel to boot from.

Comment: Which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: @Kulfy - I believe it does, I get the kernel update history. Thank you so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get list of installed packages with installation date?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087998/how-to-get-list-of-installed-packages-with-installation-date)

Comment: @MitaliCyrus You can change the pattern in `zgrep` to achieve that. The answers in the above question are more general.

Comment: @Kulfy Yes the answers in the question above more general, but my question is specific to kernel updates and hence is not addressed in the answers. If you post your solution as a answer then I can accept it since it answers my question. Thank you.