# List of installed softwares (from newest to oldest) with apt command on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, apt, 20.04

I'm looking for a way to show the list of the installed softwares ordered from newest to oldest.

So far I know only how to show the list of installed softwares:

```
apt list --installed
```

or:

```
apt list -i
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get list of installed packages with installation date?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087998/how-to-get-list-of-installed-packages-with-installation-date)

Comment: Hello @Kulfy I run the command:
zgrep 'install ' /var/log/dpkg.log* | sort | cut -f1,2,4 -d' '
but the output is quite weird because there aren't the softwares I installed today and in the previous days (e.g. gocr, texlive-extra-utils, okular etc.)

Comment: It should be there. The output doesn't seem to be sorted on the basis of date. So, your question is certainly not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

not an apt command, but you can find the history of your installs in `/var/log/apt/history.log`

For scripts and methods to generate a sorted list, I suggest you take a look at the following question: [List packages on an apt based system by installation date](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12578/list-packages-on-an-apt-based-system-by-installation-date).

Comment: Hello @bobmorane thank you for your suggestion; I'm looking for something more orderly..the file history.log is a messy

Comment: There is no internal apt database of what was installed when. Dpkg and Apt have no concept of time. Parsing the history is the ONLY way to find historical data. The linked thread (good find!) shows you how to make it less messy.

Comment: Hello @user535733 is it possible to get my goal by using a third-party product?