# Linux application installed date

Tags: syslinux

I need to get the installed date of linux applications from `/usr/share/applications/` as I am be able to get the Name of the installed applications using this command

```
sed -ns '1F;/^\[Desktop Entry\]/,/^\[/{/^Name=/p;/^Exec=/h};${z;x;G;p}' /usr/share/applications/*.desktop
```

Comment: You may be able to get the created date with "ls -lah" but that can be manipulated with touch. If it's not manipulated though, it should correspond to the installation date

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get list of installed packages with installation date?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087998/how-to-get-list-of-installed-packages-with-installation-date)

Comment: You've tagged your question is about the boot loader found on a *legacy* floppy drive or disk, how does that relate?